# Tkinter - Spinbox looks longer than expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tkinter

Running Python3.7 downloaded from python.org on macOS Mojave.

I use the following code to line up a `Spinbox` and a `Scale` to control the same variable. However, the look isn't what I expected:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
mainframe = tk.Frame(root)

# Model

input = tk.DoubleVar(value=0.)
# input = tk.IntVar(value=0)
spin = tk.Spinbox(mainframe, textvariable=input, wrap=True)
slide = tk.Scale(mainframe, variable=input, orient='horizontal')
spin['to'] = 1.0
spin['from'] = 0.0
spin['increment'] = 0.01
slide['to'] = 1.0
slide['from'] = 0.0

# spin['to'] = 100
# spin['from'] = 0
# spin['increment'] = 1
# slide['to'] = 100
# slide['from'] = 0

# Layout

weights = {'spin': 1, 'slide': 1000}

mainframe.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=weights['spin'])
mainframe.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=weights['slide'])
spin.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')
slide.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='news')

root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

I expect that the `Scale` would take more room than the `Spinbox`, but it turns out to be the opposite.

[image: Result]

I had thought that maybe it's because I used `DoubleVar` where the string could get long due to the decimal problem, but `IntVar` gives me the same result. See the code blocks that are commented out.

What's wrong? How should I get a short `Spinbox` and a long `Scale` out of this situation? Is this macOS specific, where OS imposes some min sizes on widgets?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly giving the spinbox a width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Some tkinter widgets have default value for some of their attributes.*

> A `Spinbox` has a default width of **`20`** (in **character units**), unless specified.
>
> A `Scale` has a default length of **`100`** (in **pixels**), unless specified.

So this is the reason, why you are getting the `Spinbox` to be so large and the `Scale` relatively small.

To fix it, you can specify them yourselves as in:

```
spin = tk.Spinbox(mainframe, textvariable=input, wrap=True, width=1)
slide = tk.Scale(mainframe, variable=input, orient='horizontal', length=200)
```

[image: Result]

Comment: OK, I had the wrong idea that the grid system will take care of widget resizing with weights alone, and widgets are completely passive in that regard, but now I know they can actively resize themselves. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can set width of Spinbox. For example:

```
spin = tk.Spinbox(mainframe, textvariable=input, wrap=True, width=5)
```